# Pandas dataframe grouping by multiple columns and dropping duplicate rows

Tags: python, pandas, bioinformatics

I am trying to do a task (in bioinformatics, TCGA data) using a dataframe of the following form:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['TCGA-AB-0001','TCGA-AB-0001','TCGA-AB-0001','TCGA-AB-0001','TCGA-AB-0002','TCGA-AB-0002','TCGA-AB-0002','TCGA-AB-0002','TCGA-AB-0003','TCGA-AB-0002'],
              'Reference':['HG19','HG18','HG19','GRCh37','HG18','HG19','GRCh37','HG19','GRCh37','GRCh37'],
             'SampleType':['Tumor','Tumor','Normal','Normal','Tumor','Normal','Normal','Tumor','Tumor','Tumor']
               })
```

which looks like:

```
             ID Reference SampleType
0  TCGA-AB-0001      HG19      Tumor
1  TCGA-AB-0001      HG18      Tumor
2  TCGA-AB-0001      HG19     Normal
3  TCGA-AB-0001    GRCh37     Normal
4  TCGA-AB-0002      HG18      Tumor
5  TCGA-AB-0002      HG19     Normal
6  TCGA-AB-0002    GRCh37     Normal
7  TCGA-AB-0002      HG19      Tumor
8  TCGA-AB-0003    GRCh37      Tumor
9  TCGA-AB-0002    GRCh37      Tumor
```

I am trying to match pairs of rows if they have the same 'Reference' and different 'SampleType'. The result will be a new dataframe of the following form:

```
             TUMOR                                     NORMAL
index        ID Reference SampleType      index        ID Reference SampleType
0  TCGA-AB-0001      HG19      Tumor      2  TCGA-AB-0001      HG19     Normal
7  TCGA-AB-0002      HG19      Tumor      5  TCGA-AB-0002      HG19      Tumor
9  TCGA-AB-0002    GRCh37      Tumor      6  TCGA-AB-0002    GRCh37     Normal
```

Now I would like to drop duplicate IDs but to do so the priority is according to the list [GRCh37, HG19, HG18]. So if for example both HG19 and HG18 exist with the same ID, I will keep HG19. The result should look like the following:

```
             TUMOR                                     NORMAL
index        ID Reference SampleType      index        ID Reference SampleType
0  TCGA-AB-0001      HG19      Tumor      2  TCGA-AB-0001      HG19     Normal
9  TCGA-AB-0002    GRCh37      Tumor      6  TCGA-AB-0002    GRCh37     Normal
```

is there a way to do this by groupby or some other pandas function?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there any guarantee that there will be one-to-one parity between matching References with different SampleType? In other words, if we have 1,000 rows with the (HG19      Tumor) values, will there also be 1,000 rows with ( HG19      Normal)?

Comment: And what about the ID field? Should each row in your example output df have matching IDs?

Comment: No to both questions. For example in the example I've used here, row 1 has no normal match. Also row 8 has an ID which is unique (no other row with that ID).

Comment: I think the answer to first part of the question is to use:
`df.groupby(['ID','Reference']).filter(lambda x:set(x.SampleType)=={'Tumor','Normal'})`
But I don't know how to do the second part.

Comment: Did either of the answers here provide a solution for you? If so, you should accept it so that it is no longer listed as being open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is still not 100% clear to me what the desired output is. But this seems to do the trick based on my understanding.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['TCGA-AB-0001','TCGA-AB-0001','TCGA-AB-0001','TCGA-AB-0001','TCGA-AB-0002','TCGA-AB-0002','TCGA-AB-0002','TCGA-AB-0002','TCGA-AB-0003','TCGA-AB-0002', 'TCGA-AB-0001', 'TCGA-AB-0001'],
              'Reference':['HG19','HG18','HG19','GRCh37','HG18','HG19','GRCh37','HG19','GRCh37','GRCh37', 'GRCh37', 'GRCh37'],
             'SampleType':['Tumor','Tumor','Normal','Normal','Tumor','Normal','Normal','Tumor','Tumor','Tumor', 'Normal', 'Tumor']
               })
```

This is slightly longer than the original example and tests having redundant candidate rows.

```
              ID Reference SampleType
0   TCGA-AB-0001      HG19      Tumor
1   TCGA-AB-0001      HG18      Tumor
2   TCGA-AB-0001      HG19     Normal
3   TCGA-AB-0001    GRCh37     Normal
4   TCGA-AB-0002      HG18      Tumor
5   TCGA-AB-0002      HG19     Normal
6   TCGA-AB-0002    GRCh37     Normal
7   TCGA-AB-0002      HG19      Tumor
8   TCGA-AB-0003    GRCh37      Tumor
9   TCGA-AB-0002    GRCh37      Tumor
10  TCGA-AB-0001    GRCh37     Normal
11  TCGA-AB-0001    GRCh37      Tumor
```

Now we create a temp df that may have "redundant" rows.

```
##
# Create the df with sort and first level filtering
##
df_2 = df.groupby(['ID','Reference']).filter(lambda x:set(x.SampleType)=={'Tumor','Normal'}).drop_duplicates(['ID', 'Reference', 'SampleType']).sort(['ID','Reference', 'SampleType'])
# By dropping dups and sorting, the SampleType column must alternate: Normal, Tumor, Normal...

# Break into two pieces for horizontal concat
left = df_2.iloc[np.arange(0,df_2.shape[0], 2)]
right = df_2.iloc[np.arange(1, df_2.shape[0], 2)]

# Reindex by ID so that pd.concat can properly match rows
left['old_index'] = left.index.values
left.index = left['ID']
right['old_index'] = right.index.values
right.index = right['ID']
right.columns = [c + '_2' for c in right.columns]  # Rename right side columns so we can groupby(['ID'])

# Horizontal concat
temp = pd.concat([left, right], axis=1)  # with possible duplicates for each unique (ID, Reference) tuple
temp.index = np.arange(temp.shape[0])  
temp

             ID Reference SampleType  old_index          ID_2 Reference_2  \
0  TCGA-AB-0001    GRCh37     Normal          3  TCGA-AB-0001      GRCh37
1  TCGA-AB-0001      HG19     Normal          2  TCGA-AB-0001        HG19
2  TCGA-AB-0002    GRCh37     Normal          6  TCGA-AB-0002      GRCh37
3  TCGA-AB-0002      HG19     Normal          5  TCGA-AB-0002        HG19

  SampleType_2  old_index_2
0        Tumor           11
1        Tumor            0
2        Tumor            9
3        Tumor            7
```

If I understand correctly, we only want to keep one row for each ID, choosing them in order of `priority = ['GRCh37', 'HG19', 'HG18']`

```
##
# Second level of filtering using priority list
##
priority = ['GRCh37', 'HG19', 'HG18']
g = temp.groupby(['ID'])

def filter_2(grp, priority = ['GRCh37', 'HG19', 'HG18']):
    pos = np.argsort(grp['Reference'], priority).iloc[0]
    idx = grp.index[pos]
    return grp.loc[idx, :]

final = temp.groupby(['ID']).apply(filter_2)
final.index = np.arange(final.shape[0])
```

Which yields my understanding of the final desired output. NOTE: this is different than the original example since I expanded in the input df.

```
final

             ID Reference SampleType  old_index          ID_2 Reference_2  \
0  TCGA-AB-0001    GRCh37     Normal          3  TCGA-AB-0001      GRCh37
1  TCGA-AB-0002    GRCh37     Normal          6  TCGA-AB-0002      GRCh37

  SampleType_2  old_index_2
0        Tumor           11
1        Tumor            9
```

Comment: Sorry, I lost track of things. Thanks this is what I was looking for.

Comment: Thx for checking back in. This was an interesting one. I see a lot of questions like this that generally follow the pattern of taking a tall dataframe and making it wider by joining rows on some criteria. I feel like there is (or at least should be) a more generalizable and elegant way of doing this.

Comment: Yes, I was also hoping that maybe there would a one or two-liner using groupby/filter/pivot/etc. Ideally I would like to do this on dataframes with many columns, instead of three in which case the index can also be included as an extra column. But your solution does the job, and I'm not sure there's a more compact way to do it. So thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

In order to create your new dataframes you can use pandas conditionnal slicing: (in your question you made a mistake on the dataframe `NORMAL` on the line with index 5, the `SampleType` should be `Normal` not `Tumor`)

```
NORMAL = df[df['SampleType']=='Normal'].copy()
TUMOR = df[df['SampleType']=='Tumor'].copy()
```

or if you have a chance to have anything else than `'normal'` and `'tumor'` and you wan't to get everything but `'normal'`:

```
NORMAL = df[df['SampleType']=='Normal']
TUMOR = df[~df['SampleType']=='Normal']
```

Then in order to drop the duplicates and keep the specific values, you can create another column which keeps the same information but made out of integers (easier to sort than strings lists):

```
NORMAL['Whatever'] = 0
TUMOR['Whatever'] = 0
```

Of course you can do this before splitting your dataframe df (then you only do it on one dataframe instead of two). Complete this column:

```
NORMAL.ix[NORMAL['Reference'] == 'HG19','Whatever'] = 1
TUMOR.ix[TUMOR['Reference'] == 'HG19','Whatever'] = 1
NORMAL.ix[NORMAL['Reference'] == 'HG18','Whatever'] = 2
TUMOR.ix[TUMOR['Reference'] == 'HG18','Whatever'] = 2
```

Then sort by this new column, and drop the duplicates, keeping only the first row:

```
NORMAL.sort_values(by = 'Whatever', inplace = True)
NORMAL.drop_duplicates(subset = 'ID',inplace = True)
TUMOR.sort_values(by = 'Whatever', inplace = True)
TUMOR.drop_duplicates(subset = 'ID',inplace = True)
```

And in order to get the expected output, delete the temporary column, and resort by index:

```
NORMAL.drop('Whatever',1,inplace = True)
NORMAL.sort_index(inplace = True)
TUMOR.drop('Whatever',1,inplace = True)
TUMOR.sort_index(inplace = True)
```

OUTPUT:

```
Out[3]: NORMAL
    ID              Reference   SampleType
3   TCGA-AB-0001    GRCh37      Normal
6   TCGA-AB-0002    GRCh37      Normal


Out[32]: TUMOR
    ID              Reference   SampleType
0   TCGA-AB-0001    HG19        Tumor
8   TCGA-AB-0003    GRCh37      Tumor
9   TCGA-AB-0002    GRCh37      Tumor
```